# In Azure B2C how to restrict user from signing up/in with same email through social media(gmail) and Local Account(Email)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, google-signin

I came across this issue in my app, that azure is letting user register themselves from email and social media (using registered email) both. Thus there are two users with same email Id.

Can you guys help me out in this one?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are expecting to happen?

Comment: Thank you for responding Chris. 
I have an angular application that is secured by Azure B2C(using MSAL library). User can use google, facebook and email to sign in/up. The problem is when user signs up with email new objectId is created, and when the same user with same email signs-in via google then different user with different objectId is created. I want to restrict this creation of two different accounts with same email from any identity provider and prompt user a message that the user with this email Id already exists. How that can I do that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As of now in basic policies, it is not possible. But in advanced policies (IEF) you can make a trick by calling an API to check user email existence using Graph APIs and return success or exception.

There is an account linking feature which is in the roadmap and you can vote for that at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13214529-azure-ad-b2c-how-to-avoid-validate-duplicate-s

Comment: This trick of calling external API from my custom policy didn't work because we can't intercept sign-in sign-up calls from social media.

I tried creating a REST API that will take email as an input claim in my custom policy(TrustFrameworkExtensions) and further hit Graph API to check that this email exists in B2C or not will work only for local accounts and not for social media accounts.

Comment: Hey Rama... can you please shed some light here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58276894/114029